# Aspose Words Document doesnt load my FormFields

Tags: .net, ms-word, aspose.words

I'm having an issue right now with document creation. I've created a Word docx document containing several MergeField elements. My document content's is saved to my db, and later on I retrieve it somewhere else in my code using
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(byte[]);
Document doc = new Document(myStream);

When I try to access my form merge fields using doc.Range.FormFields, the list is empty. I'm wondering why because I can still see the formating of my MergeField elements when I do doc.Range.GetText();

Could you please help me figure this out. I've been struggling for some time. See below for the content of my document after I access its Range's text. I've also attached a screenshot of my content where we can see my MERGE FIELD elements' tags.

Raw Content:

```
 PAGE   \* MERGEFORMAT 1
Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2010 Aspose Pty Ltd.
2011 Marine Liability Quote

 MERGEFIELD  FieldAMapped \m  \* MERGEFORMAT «FieldAMapped»  MERGEFIELD  FieldB  \* MERGEFORMAT «FieldB»  MERGEFIELD  FieldC  \* MERGEFORMAT «FieldC»  MERGEFIELD  FieldDMapped \m  \* MERGEFORMAT «FieldDMapped»




Assured:    [[InsuredCompanyName]]
    [[InsuredAddress]]
    [[InsuredCity]], [[InsuredState]], [[InsuredZip]]
    [[InsuredContactFirstName]] [[InsuredContactLastName]]

Coverage(s):    Commercial Marine Liability

Effective:    12 Months at [[PolicyEffectiveDate]] (MM/DD/YYYY)

Deductible:    $ per occurrence

Commission:    [[DistributorCommission]] %

Premium:    $ [[TotalGrossPremiumAmount]]

Security:    Starr Indemnity & Liability Company (A.M. Best A, FSC X)

Coverage Premiums:   
Coverage TypeGross Premium[[OW_REPEAT_BEGIN]] [[Premium_PremiumType]]$[[Premium_Amount]][[OW_REPEAT_END]]      State Surcharge$[[TotalTaxesAmount]]Total$[[TotalGrossPremiumAmount]]    
    Limits:
Coverage PartCoverage TypeLimit[[OW_REPEAT_BEGIN]][[Limit_PremiumType]][[Limit_Description]]$[[Limit_Amount]][[OW_REPEAT_END]]


Conditions:[[InsuringConditions]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, in such scenarios, we might require some documents and other details from your end in order to investigate the issue; we might also need to log the issues and then follow up, in such cases. And this is something we can do via our own support forums.

You may contact our support team via [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) and discuss this matter in detail.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.